# Deleting and Reassigning a pointer from QList<Object *> to new Object using Iterator, is this right?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QList and I'm trying to replace the objects in the list with new objects. The context is that I have a list of custom objects (the class name is "Conversation") to represent a list of group chats in a messaging platform. I use std::find_if to iterate through the list of pointers to find one with the right ID, and I want to take the pointer to that found object, deallocate it (delete?), and reassign that pointer to point at an object I generate with the "new" keyword. I think I'm doing this right but I'm not sure how to verify.

I tried a couple different iterations, ran into some issues where I realized I was using a const_iterator rather than just an iterator, so I couldn't modify any data. But I've fixed that and it seems like it's working, but I'm not positive.

Here's what I've got:

```cpp
GroupChat *gc = new GroupChat(); // extends Conversation
// ...I update the member data here...

auto foundChat = std::find_if(conversations_.Conversations.begin2(),
 conversations_.Conversations.end2(),
 [this, gc](Conversation* o) { // my code to find the correct one...
}

if (foundChat != conversations_.Conversations.end()) {
    auto c = (*foundChat);
    delete c; // Is this right? Not positive...
    //*foundChat = nullptr; // do I need this?
    c = gc;
}
```

It seems like it's working but I'm worried about dangling pointers and incorrect memory deallocation/allocation. Could someone spot check me on this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: ***//*foundChat = nullptr; // do I need this?** No.

Comment: `c=gc;` is wrong: that just assigns to the local variable.  Maybe you want `auto &c=*foundChat;`?

Comment: @drescherjm Okay great, thanks!
@DavisHerring That looks right! So, if I use that, would using `c = gc;` successfully change the pointer that the iterator found?

Comment: @IanBurns: Er, probably—so long as `QList` isn’t doing something weird and error-prone.  (If it doesn’t compile, Qt is being weird but not error-prone.)

Comment: @DavisHerring Perfect! It seems to compile and update, I think I just need to get my QAbstractListModel updating now to reflect the pointer change. Thank you!